# X and Y labels are too close to heatmap

Tags: r

How can I move it a bit further ? I use such code for heatmap:

```
heatmap(mat_cor_results,Rowv=NA, Colv=NA,scale="none", col=hmcols, xlab= "BBB", ylab= "CCC") ##plot heatmap
```

It's too close to the heatmap and it doesn't look so nice...
Any ideas how to change it ?

[image: Heamap]

Comment: See `?par`'s `mgp` argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intention is to move the text in `xlab` and `ylab` you can simply use `margins = c(10,10)`, as in the code below:

```
# Data cand chart
data(mtcars)
corr_cars <- cor(mtcars)
heatmap(corr_cars, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, scale="none", xlab= "BBB", ylab= "CCC", 
        margins = c(10,10))
```

Would give you the following heatmap:
[image: massive distance]

If your intention is to move the value axis labels you can do:

```
# Data cand chart with massive margins
data(mtcars)
corr_cars <- cor(mtcars)
# Insane space
par(mgp=c(5,5,5))
heatmap(corr_cars, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, scale="none", xlab= "BBB", ylab= "CCC", 
        margins = c(10,10))
```

which would produce:

[image: massive space]